# Pinescript backtest specific days of week

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Trying to code entry on the open of certain bar and exit on the close of the same bar. And to make it on a certain day of week. This is to backtest different days of week.

I tried to create code that will enter on the open of certain day of week (for example Monday) and will exit on the close of this day. But it seemed impossible for me, because I didnt found an operator that will let me to do it. For now my code looks like:

//@version=5
strategy("Ma strategy", overlay=true)

long_entry = dayofweek(time) == 6 // Friday
long_exit = dayofweek(time) == 2 // Monday

if (long_entry) and year(time) == 2023
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.short)

if (long_exit)
strategy.close("Long", immediately = true) \

This lets to exit on the close of Monday and to enter on the open of the day next to Friday. This is a problem, most of days next to Fridays are Mondays but not everything. So thats why there can be false enters. How is it possible, if it is, to enter on the open of the day and to exit on the close of the same day?